# What is the pthread_cond_wait() & pthread_cond_signal() calling sequence?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, ipc, mutex

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t lockid;
pthread_cond_t cvar = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
char name[14];

void *entry()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockid);

    printf("Enter Name\n");
    scanf("%s",name);

    pthread_cond_signal(&cvar);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *display()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lockid);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cvar,&lockid);

    printf("Name: %s\n",name);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t id1,id2;
    if(pthread_mutex_init(&lockid,NULL)== 0){
        pthread_create(&id1,NULL,&entry,NULL);
        pthread_create(&id2,NULL,&display,NULL);

        pthread_join(id1,NULL);
        pthread_join(id2,NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting that the thread id2 to print the name that I have entered on thread id1.
I know it's the `pthread_cond_wait()`doesn't allow the thread `id2` to display the name entered on thread `id1` but `signal()` should be called before `wait()` right ?
Is the way of calling `wait()` and `signal()` methods correct?  I am new to linux programming please help me on this.

Comment: "not working" is never a good problem description. Can you please describe the exact expected behaviour vs actual behaviour?

Comment: @kaylum : When I ran the program the name that I have entered in the thread 1 is not displayed on the thread 2 which is my expected behavior, but its simply waits for the signal that should be sent by thread 1.

Comment: When I ran your code `display()` is waiting on `pthread_mutex_lock(&lockid);` when `entry()` sends `pthread_cond_signal(&cvar);` and subsequently exits.  Per man "If  no threads  are  waiting  on  cond,  nothing  happens.", i.e. wait needs to be executed before but the signal but your code doesn't arrange for that.

Comment: @AllanWind : Yes Allan but the thread 2 is waiting for the thread 1 to complete right ??

Comment: In my run, `display()` thread was waiting on the mutex so it has yet to execute `pthread_cond_wait()`.  You need `display()` to  execute `pthread_cond_wait` before you run the `entry()` thread at least as defined.  I added a sleep to `entry()` as a quick way to test that idea.

Comment: @AllanWind : So what is the correct way of synchronizing this code ? Can you show me Allan ?? and If thread 2 has the mutex lockid how can thread 1 uses entry function ??

Comment: If you need two things to run in sequential order why are you using threads?

Comment: @AllanWind : Its just for my under standing, but If thread 2 has the mutex lock how can thread 1 uses entry function ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sequential task don't use threads:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char name[14];

int main() {
    printf("Enter Name\n");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    return 0
}
```

You can use a `state` variable to ensure that `entry()` run before `display()`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

pthread_mutex_t lockid;
pthread_cond_t cvar = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
char name[14];
enum { START, ENTRY } state = START;
#define CHECK(e) { int error = (e); if(error) printf("%s:%d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, strerror(error)); }
#define CHECK2(p, e) { if(p) CHECK(e); }


void *entry() {
    CHECK(pthread_mutex_lock(&lockid));
    printf("Enter Name\n");
    CHECK2(scanf("%s", name) == EOF, errno);
    state = ENTRY;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cvar);
    CHECK(pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockid));
    return 0;
}

void *display() {
    CHECK(pthread_mutex_lock(&lockid));
    while(state != ENTRY) pthread_cond_wait(&cvar, &lockid);
    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    CHECK(pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockid));
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    pthread_mutex_init(&lockid, NULL);
    pthread_t id1, id2;
    CHECK(pthread_create(&id1, NULL, &entry, NULL));
    CHECK(pthread_create(&id2, NULL, &display, NULL));
    CHECK(pthread_join(id1,NULL));
    CHECK(pthread_join(id2,NULL));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Last code snippet is wrong if you get a spurious wakeup. You should wrap `pthread_cond_wait` in a loop and use `name`'s content as the exit condition (keep looping till e.g. first character is no longer NUL).

Comment: @a3f [There's no "should" about it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html#tag_16_420#tag_16_420_08_01): "It is important to note that when `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_timedwait()` return without error, the associated predicate may still be false. Similarly, when `pthread_cond_timedwait()` returns with the timeout error, the associated predicate may be true due to an unavoidable race between the expiration of the timeout and the predicate state change."

Comment: (cont) "The application needs to recheck the predicate on any return because it cannot be sure there is another thread waiting on the thread to handle the signal, and if there is not then the signal is lost. **The burden is on the application to check the predicate.**"

Comment: Thanks. I dropped the last example.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I added the recheck.  As far as I can tell the man page on Linux does not mention that requirement.

Comment: Since the return from `pthread_cond_timedwait()` or `pthread_cond_wait()` does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return. -- [Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_wait.3p.html)

Comment: The `while` loop is sufficient. You don't need the `if` check with `goto`. Of course, the code is also missing checks for error return values.